# Que diferencia hay entre la carpeta Res y de Assets en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Me pregunto si `assets` y `res` son lo mismo en Android, es que a veces me encuentro ejemplos que hacen referencias a recursos en assets y otros en res, me está liando un poco.

Comment: Una pregunta muy parecida (en *inglés*): [Difference between /res and /assets directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)

Comment: @x4m73r Si más o menos el enlace que a comentado PaulVargas viene a decir eso que comentas, saludos.

Comment: @x4mp73r Agrega lo que comentas como respuesta, creo que es buena información!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estas serían las diferencias mas notables entre `/res` y `/assets`:

#### `/assets`

- Dentro de este folder se agregan archivos que cuando es generado el paquete .apk conservan su nombre y características.
- Se pueden agregar archivos con mayúsculas o signos lo cual no es permitido dentro de `/res`.
- Dentro de este folder incluso se puede crear una estructura de archivos.

Ejemplo:

```
assets
 |__Directorio
 |__miBasedeDato
 |__ArchivosAndroid
```

- La clase R no genera ids para los elementos almacenados en este folder
- Una diferencia importante es que dentro de /assets se agregan elementos los cuales pueden ser leídos como un Stream de bytes.

#### `/res`

- Contiene recursos de la aplicación como son layouts, imágenes (drawables), strings, etc.
- La principal diferencia con respecto a `/assets` es que estos recursos son accedidos a través de la clase R, que es generada automáticamente por el proyecto y contiene ids que hacen referencia a cada recurso dentro de `/res`.
- Otra diferencia es que dentro de `/res`, únicamente se permiten archivos con nombres que contengan caracteres en letra minúscula de "a" a la "z" y numéricos de 0 a 9.

Answer (score 2):

Por experiencia, en Res van todos los recursos de Android que puedes hacer uso o crearlos tu mismo, por ejemplo, animaciones, estilos, layouts extra, etc. Ya en la carpeta `assets` irían todos los recursos extra que puedes usar y que no sean de Android, por ejemplo fuentes y archivos multimedia. En mi caso, ahí he colocado videos, archivos ogg, fuentes, etc. Hasta incluso archivos `html` y `css`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]